# Doctrine DBAL issue

Tags: doctrine, dbal

This used to work in DBAL 2 but throws the error Named parameter "receivedOn" does not have a bound value in DBAL 3.  Trying to make sense of it - if anyone able to make any pointers?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fyky.png

Answer (score 1):

You should pass parameters names in $params like:

```php
$params = [
    'name' => $event->getSomething()
];
```

Comment: Comment made from text removed from this answer: *Next time, please, copy your code here. It is harder to answer you without code.*